# GCM to FCM Web Push

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have some project that works with GCM to send web push (https://curiosity-driven.org/push-notifications), using tokens/endpoints that were collected from the browsers/users.

```
function subscribe() {
    return serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
        return registration.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true
        });
    }).then(function(subscription) {
        return subscription.endpoint; //Stored in DB
    });
}
```

But in Firebase we also need some **p256dh** and **auth** keys to send notifications. Is there any way to get these keys from existing(old) GCM tokens/endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Firebase we also need some p256dh and auth keys to send notifications

That's not true. You only need those keys to send a payload with the notification (otherwise you can just send a signal and then fetch the notifications from the server). You are probably confusing those key for the payload with the VAPID keys.

> Is there any way to get these keys from existing(old) GCM tokens/endpoints?

No. You need to read the subscription again from the client with Javascript.